# Cheerio doesn't return content added dynamically

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I have the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const options = {
    uri: `https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/51403409?search_identifier=620f645adbd75033ae2faf2cffdcfc3a`,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
    },
    transform: function (body) {
      return cheerio.load(body);
    }
};

rp(options)
    .then(($) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < $('img').length; i++) {
            console.log($('img')[i].attribs.src)
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Although the class is in the mark up the array under the page /results is returning empty.

I am thinking that the img classes are added dynamically that's possibly why are not getting picked up.

Is there a way around that if that's the case?

**UPDATE**

I have updated the code however I am getting not the expected result:

[image]

I would expect to find urls of .png or .jpg

**2nd UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried logging `$('.gallery-thumbs-list img')` out to the console to see what it's returning. If you look at the page source there are elements that conform to `.gallery-thumbs-list img` so it doesn't appear that they are being dynamically loaded (at least not all of them anyway)

Comment: If I run this in the node console 'console.log($('img').length)' I get 1 and it refers to: http://media.rightmove.co.uk/sitelogo.gif

Comment: The web server detected that you are not using a browser to load the page content. For me, it served an error page without any `.gallery-thumbs-list` elements. Using a `User-Agent` header for the request should make it work

Comment: I meant console.log in the node process. 
@corschdi Ah yep that's probably the issue.

Comment: I have updated the code with the user agent but it doesn't seem I am getting a list of all the images url/ src attributes

Comment: I have disabled JavaScript and and only 1 image with that class is coming through the HTML so the content for that images is dynamic. I guess I will need to find a way to load it after.

Comment: I see them in `.dp-gallery__list-item img`

Comment: @pguardiario if I console.log your suggestion I see the object (screenshot attached under 2nd update) but I don't see any img tags or related to that. Also this ($('.dp-gallery__list-item img').length) results in returning 0

Comment: There's two things, in chrome element inspector do ctrf-f and paste that selector, you will see 9 of them. If cheerio can't find them though you might be getting a bad response.